# Undefined reference to XOpenDisplay in a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, xlib

Now I am feeling quite stupid. I am trying to do some stuff with xlib in Qt Creator.

My code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Just one line of code and gives me:

```
/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
```

It is defined in Xlib.h as

```
extern Display *XOpenDisplay(
    _Xconst char* /* display_name */
);
```

I feel I am missing something very basic.

Comment: @cz-david Did you add XLib to LIB in your Qt project file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Adding `-lX11` to the the `Makefile` solved this issue.

Comment: where do you add in Qt Creator

Comment: Projects - Build steps - Additional arguments

Comment: @Meltea
This doesn't seem to work on qmake in Qt 5.5.1
How do I make it work? It is saying that -lX11 is not a known argument.

Comment: What make file? There isn't a make file mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'm getting the same  error calling the make file for [another project](https://github.com/jumper149/blugon), and the surprising thing is that if I pull out all the flags used in the makefile and call gcc in the command line e.g. `gcc scg.c  -O2 -std=c11 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  -lX11 -lXrandr -o scg`, then it compiles & links, but calling it with Make it does not work. How can this be?? 

Answer (score 2):

@КодСерфинг145 I added `LIBS += -lX11` to the make file (the .pro file)
Adding Additional arguments to Build steps inside Projects did not work for me either and neither did `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lX11` like many suggests.